# C++ Segmentation fault BST

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I'm currently working on a c++ implementation of a binary search tree. Everything seems to be working perfectly, but my search function is giving me issues.

```
BinarySearchTree::node* BinarySearchTree::SEARCH(node* x, int key)
{
    if(root == NULL) {
            cout << "This is an empty tree." << endl;
            return NULL;

    } else {
            if(x->key == key) {
                    return x;
            }
            if(x == NULL) {
                    cout << "Value not in tree." << endl;
                    return x;
            }
            if(key < x->key ) {
                    return SEARCH(x->left, key);
            } else {
                    return SEARCH(x->right, key);
            }
    }
}
```

This gives me a segmentation fault every time I search for a key value that is not in the tree, and when the node value is NULL (such as a value that would be either the max or min if it were included).

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a debugger. And you're checking if `x` is null after you dereference it.

Comment: I've never used a debugger in a UNIX environment, suppose I should figure out how to do that by now =P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check NULL pointer first and then the rest. If x is NULL, accessing key by `x->key` will give you segmentation fault.

```
if(x == NULL) {
  cout << "Value not in tree." << endl;
  return x;
}
if(x->key == key) {
  return x;
}
...
```

Comment: Dang it! I knew it was going to be something stupid I was missing. Thank you.